# Verify / validate the data before calling insert()

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am using Zend's `insert()` function to insert records in a database table.
Eg.
From the database model object, I am calling `Zend_Db_Table's  insert()` function and passing the incoming data as an array - `$data`, ie

```
 $this->insert($data);
```

`$data` is an array. The contents of `$data` are of mixed datatypes -integer, money, text etc.

In order to validate the incoming `$data` array, I wrote a function, `verifyData($data)`.

```
private function verifyData(&$data) {
    //Trim whitespace characters from incoming data.
    foreach($data as $key => $val)
    {
        $data[$key] = trim($val);
        if(empty($data[$key])) {
            unset($data[$key]);
        }
    }

    //Checking for not null table columns
    if( empty($data['id']) || empty($data['name']) || empty($data['age'])) {
        error_log("One of the required fields is missing");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

As written above,this function :

1. trims the incoming data and unsets any fields from the $data array, if they are empty.
2. Then this function checks for the presence of required fields and if any required field is missing, it returns false. In this particular definition, id, name and age are required. However, there could be other non required fields as well that I want to validate. Eg $data['salary']

I need help/suggestions in adding following validations to the above function / in any other way possible:

1. I want to check if the datatype of each element of the array is as expected/ convert it to a particular datatype before I insert the data.
2. I want to convert/process the incoming data such that any threat of SQL injection is taken care of.

One way to take care of the datatype check is that I loop through the incoming data array and convert specific column values to their datatypes and validate. But I want to find out if there is any efficient/standard way to implement the above two points.

An example scenario is, eg on my webform, when the new person is added to db, I need to enter name, age and salary out of which name and age are compulsory. Age and salary should be entered as integers only. I want to implement this restriction on the php level and I am using Zend Framework.

Any help/suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: If you want suggestions on how to adapt your existing function, at the very least you have to show the code of that function.

Comment: ZombieHunter and Jeroen : Sorry if it was not clear. I updated my question now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to start might be with [Zend_filter_Input](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html), which uses Zend_Validation and Zend_Filter to apply filtering and validation to a dataset.

```
//A simple exaample of how you might use Zend_Filter_Input
private function verifyData(&$data) {
    //Add any filters you want there are many standard filters, order of filters may matter
    $filters = array(
        '*' => 'StringTrim', //trim all fields
        'id' => 'Digits'     //filter for digits on id field
    );
    //add any validators you want there are many standard validators, order of validators may matter
    $validators = array(
        '*' => 'NotEmpty' //check all fields for empty()
    );
$input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators, $data) {
    if ($input->isValid() {
       return TRUE;
    } else {
       return FALSE
    }    
}
```

Needless to say this an incomplete example of how this works but it should give you the basic idea. There are many different ways to accomplish validation, find one you like and go for it.

My personal favorite is to do basic filtering and validation at the input stage (forms, controller...) and then to apply any other filtering or validation in the domain model prior to sending the data to the mapper to be inserted into the database.

Good Luck...

[Standard Filters](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.set.html)
[Standard Vaildators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html)

Answer (score 0):

`insert` should already take care of any SQL injection problems you might run into. As for type-checking and conversion, there are several methods available in PHP. For example, checking for and converting to an `int`:

```
if(ctype_digit($something)) {
    $something = (int)$something;
}
```

It really depends on the specific validation you need.

Comment: Thanks @minitech. I agree one way is that I check specific fields for specific datatypes. But if I have too many columns in one table, I was hoping to find a better solution to do the above instead of checking each one sequentially.